# Android studio doing nothing

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using android studio 1.4 and just switched to the 1.5.1 but then I experience some issue. When I try to launch my app I can see android studio building the gradle and doing something, but I manage to launch the app only when my android studio session is new. Alias if I fix a bug in my app then want to restart, then android studio is building the gradle, doing I dont know what and then nothing is happening...

I tried real phone and simulator, same issue.
Below is my launch config
[image]

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the cause is your workspace configuration. You can try to close project then open the project again through opening the project file using "Open an existing Android Studio project" option instead of clicking the recent projects... Then Clean project and then Rebuild project afterwards. Tell me if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that looks to work so far

1) I remove that "Gradle-aware make" config from the launch script and leave it empty
2) I do my launch in 2 step: first I build an apk via Build->Build apk
3) Then I launch my configuration that is basically just installing this new apk on the phone.

No idea why the whole operation do not want to be done in one go, but doing this way so far it works quite well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while making a build for android in react-native project
I researched and found out this error occurs in 3.x.x versions only 
my android studio version 3.6.1

did the following steps to fix the issue:
1) run > edit configuration > (at bottom) before launch: Gradle-Aware make 
first, 
2) removed it
3) add it back while adding it will ask select Gradle task leave it empty. hit ok
4) restart your android studio and load the project from option Open existing project not from recent projects to reflect the setting,

also, make sure your manifest file doesn't have any closing tag or unclosed comment pending

after the restart, it will start working!!