# Unable to use breakpoints in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

I just installed the latest version of Android Studio, my computers OS is Windows 10 x64.

The problem is that for some reason Android Studio wont hit the breakpoints.. no matter if I use my nexus 10 with USB-debugging enabled, or if I use a VM.. however.. the app gets "published" to the selected device and launched.

This is my build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Any ideas?

I have Unity3D installed on the same machine but there is currently no process thats associated with Unity3D running.. and adb devices do list the connected device(s)..

I have also tried to run adb kill-server and adb start-server.. but that didnt do it either..

Br,
Inx

Comment: I think your problem is on the workspace configuration. You can try to follow my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958604/android-studio-doing-nothing/34958764#34958764)

Comment: temporarly disabled my windows firewall as well.. no result..

Comment: did you press the debug button instead of the usual play button?

Comment: Yes, the one with the bug